Superset 4.0.2 : Table Chart - Column Based Total Calculation
I recently started using Superset 4.0.2. As in the example I added above, I want to create a table with the total of the column below in the table I created. I would be very glad if you could help me how I can do this.
This is the output table chart I wanted
Looks like;
                       A       B      C

groupa                 1       2      3

groupb                 4       5      6

Total                  5       7      9

I did try pivot table and table charts, but it didn't work.
